# Is it possible to start a service with a shortcut?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a shortcut on the home screen that, when pressed, will start a service instead of an activity.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the service doing? What about just setting up a receiver to listen to something the service uses to launch it instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a dummy Activity that simply starts a Service, then finishes itself:

```
public class MyServiceActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: True. I was taking him literally, but that would certainly work. You might have to play with the theme a bit, though, so you don't get a momentary flash of an activity.

Comment: This code definitely works and this is what my code currently does. I was trying to skip the extra activity step.

Comment: Be sure your users understand what's going on, though. I can see this sort of thing garnering a lot of one-star, "tapped the shorcut and nothing happened" complaints on the Market.

Comment: CommonsWare, how would you go about changing the theme to get rid of the "momentary flash" of an activity?  Did you solve this issue gnobal?

Comment: in case someone still wonders, [this post](http://gnobal.net/2053/creating-a-transparent-activity-in-android) explains how to get rid of the "flash".

Answer (score 7):

No, sorry. Shortcuts only launch activities.

Comment: So is there any official way to create a widget/shortcut to start a service? (to send a network request)? Shortcuts can only start activities, widgets are not the same style as a shortcut. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasVos: An app widget can use a `PendingIntent` to start an activity, start a service, or send a broadcast. Just tie it to something in the app widget's UI (e.g., a button) to be invoked when that UI is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would work, but I would like the 1x1 widget to have the same style as a "shortcut".

Comment: @ThomasVos: Since the style of the shortcut is up to the home screen implementation, I fail to see how your objective is practical.